# Javascript remove hidden iframe and url replace with another url make script work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden

Hi I'm trying to get a script working properly. Theres a link to a site that opens up in an iframe and the dates dont go green for the day it is. and I cant find the iframe and url and get another url there but to open up in a new window. Any help would be appreciated heres a link to the script.
https://codepen.io/bengoddard/pen/boeEy

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var weekday = [];
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var currentDay = weekday[currentDate.getDay()];

var currentTimeHours = currentDate.getHours();
currentTimeHours = currentTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + currentTimeHours : currentTimeHours;
var currentTimeMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var timeNow = currentTimeHours + "" + currentTimeMinutes;

var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //this works at hightlighting today

var openTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.opens').text().split(":");

var openTimeHours = openTimeSplit[0];
openTimeHours = openTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + openTimeHours : openTimeHours;

var openTimeMinutes = openTimeSplit[1];
var openTimex = openTimeSplit[0] + openTimeSplit[1];

var closeTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.closes').text().split(":");

var closeTimeHours = closeTimeSplit[0];
closeTimeHours = closeTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + closeTimeHours : closeTimeHours;

var closeTimeMinutes = closeTimeSplit[1];
var closeTimex = closeTimeSplit[0] + closeTimeSplit[1];

if (timeNow >= openTimex && timeNow <= closeTimex) {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("open");
} else {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("closed");
}
```

```css
.openinghours {
    font-family:Lucida Console;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.openinghourscontent {
    float:left;
}
.openinghourscontent h2 {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:.33em;
}
.openinghourscontent button {
    color:white;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size:large;
    font-weight:bolder;
    background-color:#4679BD;
    border-radius:4px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.today {
    color: #8AC007;
}
.opening-hours-table tr td:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
#open-status {
    display:block;
    margin-top:-1em;
    text-align:center;
    border:dotted lightgrey 3px;
}
.openorclosed:after {
    content:" open during these hours:";
}
.open {
    color:green;
}
.open:after {
    content:" Open";
    color: #6C0;
}
.closed:after {
    content:" Closed";
    color: red;
}
.opening-hours-table tr td {
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="openinghours">
    <div class="openinghourscontent section">
        <div class="header">
             <h2>Opening hours</h2>
 <span id="open-status"><small class="openorclosed">We are</small></span>

        </div>
        <table class="opening-hours-table">
            <tr id="Monday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Monday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tuesday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Tuesday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Wednesday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Wednesday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Thursday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Thursday at 9am to 8pm">
                <td>Thursday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">20:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Friday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Friday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Friday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Saturday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Saturday at 10am to 6pm">
                <td>Saturday</td>
                <td class="opens">10:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Sunday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Sunday at 11am to 4pm">
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td class="opens">11:00</td>
                <td>-</td>
                <td class="closes">16:00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button style="cursor: pointer;" title="Make an Apointment Online" data-appointlet="u387">Make an Apointment Online</button>
        <script>
            (function(e, t, n, r) {
                if (e) return;
                t._appt = true;
                var i = n.createElement(r),
                    s = n.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
                i.async = true;
                i.src = '//dje0x8zlxc38k.cloudfront.net/loaders/s-min.js';
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(i, s)
            })(window._appt, window, document, "script")
        </script>
    </div>
</section>
```

I added PM and Am to the script if that helps tell why it stops working.

Comment: The link one works for me and shows green for Monday.

Comment: Worked fine with me... Displaying Tuesday and on Make, appointment click opened Iframe also...

Comment: Their code works fine but when I put it on my site it stops showing new days. Also how do i get rid of the iframe and url to their site?

Comment: This one wont work. http://8mike.ca/hours.html